# Apollo Client: Keep/Reset defaults on clearing or resetting store

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-link-state

I'm using `apollo-link-state` for locally storing errors, but I get the following error after clearing cache.

I've set the default value of `errors` to an empty array `[]` in apollo client configuration options.

However, after `apolloClient.cache.reset()` or `apolloClient.store.reset()`, it seems that I lose all default values, causing this error:

[image: Error]

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html):

> Sometimes you may need to reset the store in your application, for example when a user logs out. If you call client.resetStore anywhere in your application, you will need to write your defaults to the store again. apollo-link-state exposes a writeDefaults function for you. To register your callback to Apollo Client, call client.onResetStore and pass in writeDefaults.

So you can do something like:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache()
const link = withClientState({ cache, resolvers, defaults })

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link,
})

client.onResetStore(stateLink.writeDefaults)
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work at first, it seems that `writeDefaults` has some issues. Solved by adding any `Query` to client type definitions..

Answer (score 0):

With Apollo 2.x, you can just do below:

```
cache.writeData({data : defaultData });

client.onResetStore(() => {
  cache.writeData({data : defaultData });
});
```

Assuming that you have a default data for cache set up above this code.